# Add three ints tp array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a continuous stream of in data, consisting of Integers, I need to add them to add groups of three to the database.
I have been googling for a couple day now but haven't come to a working solution.

So am I asking this brain to help me.

```
def index
    i=0
    speedData = []
    tempArray = []
    File.open("/var/www/html/speeds.txt", "r").each_line do |line|
        speedData.push(line.split(/\s/)[1].to_f.round)
        puts speedData.last
            if i<3
                tempArray.push(speedData.last)
                i=+1
            end
            puts tempArray.inspect
            #Speed.create(:ping => tempArray[0], :down => tempArray[1], :up => tempArray[2])
            i=0
            tempArray.clear
        end

    end
    puts i
end
```

This is my current solution... not working mind you. :)
So what should I do? groups_of looks like a good command but...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `in_groups_of` seems to be what you need.
If I understood correctly format for `speeds.txt` then smth like this should work:

```
def index
  File.open("/var/www/html/speeds.txt", "r").each_line do |line|
    all_numbers = line.split(/\s+/)
    all_numbers.in_groups_of(3).each do |(ping, down, up)|
      Speed.create(:ping => ping, :down => down, :up => up)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a step in the right direction the format speeds.txt is like this: Ping: 35.791 ms
Download: 26.84 Mbit/s
Upload: 4.63 Mbit/s

Comment: @swe_mattias you may wanna use regexps then: `line = "Ping: 35.791 ms Download: 26.84 Mbit/s Upload: 4.63 Mbit/s";   match = /Ping: (?<ping>\d+\.\d+).+?Download: (?<down>\d+\.\d+).+?Upload: (?<up>\d+\.\d+)/.match(line); puts [match[:up], match[:down], match[:ping]]`