# Need to refrase: How to group every second values from an array in groups of 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I posted a question here: [Add three ints tp array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620972/add-three-ints-tp-array/35622012#35622012)

But I see now after reading the good answer that I asked the wrong thing.

From the file reading I need to get the second value from every row and group these by 3.

```html
class SpeedController < ApplicationController
  def index
  File.open("/var/www/html/speeds.txt", "r").each_line do |line|
    all_numbers = line.split(/\s+/)
    all_numbers.in_groups_of(3).each do |(ping, down, up)|
      puts down
      #Speed.create(:ping => ping, :down => down, :up => up)
    end
  end
end
end
```

I hope that my explanation above can shed the light on the question I have.

I read three lines they contains
"String: FLOAT1 String"
"String: FLOAT2 String"
"String: FLOAT3 String"

I need to get the float out of three rows before I group them and insert them into the model.
Thus:
Speed.create(:ping => FLOAT1, :down => FLOAT2, :up => FLOAT3)

Now finally I think I have explained my problem enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
class SpeedController < ApplicationController
    def index
      lines = File.readlines("/var/www/html/speeds.txt")
      lines.in_groups_of(3).each do |ping, down, up|
        ping = ping.gsub(/[^0-9,\.]/, '')
        down = down.gsub(/[^0-9,\.]/, '')
        up = up.gsub(/[^0-9,\.]/, '')
        Speed.create(:ping => ping, :down => down, :up => up)
       end
    end
end
```

Basically readlines will put all the lines into an array, seems like exactly what you need.

Comment: Thank you @TomD exactly what I needed. :)